# Can we create an emulator with Hard Keyboard feature

Tags: android-emulator

Hi I am developing an application which supports Hardkeyboard. I want to test the application on virtual device. Can we create an virtual device(Emulator) with hard keyboard feature and test my application on that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While making a new virtual device in the AVD Manager, you can set the "Keyboard Support" option to "yes". But, thats the default value, so unless you explicitly set keyboard support to "no" for your virtual device, the hard keyboard should be there in your virtual device